# How to prove $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ is a singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, projection-matrices

Is there a way to prove that statement? Lets say A is a $n\times p$ matrix.

I read from my text book that this matrix is a projection matrix of rank p.

Have no idea what that means, and no luck searching for understandable literature.

Hope you guys can lend me a hand.

Thanks.

Comment: @GaryMoore The only nonsingular projection matrix is the identity. All others have a nontrivial kernel, so are singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p<n$, $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, but $$\operatorname{rank}(A(A^TA)^{-1}A) \le \min(\operatorname{rank}(A(A^TA)^{-1}), \operatorname{rank}(A))\le p<n$$

Hence, it is singular.

However, if $p=n$, the statement is not necessarily true. For example, let $A=I$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So, is it always true that if $p<n$ then a matrix is singular? Do you have some link of material I could learn this stuff? thanks.

Comment: need you to clarify the meaning of "a matrix", are you referring to the matrix stated in the question? if a matrix if of rank $p$ but it has $n$ rows and $n$ columns and $n>p$, then it is singular. Wikipedia page of invertible matrix is helpful. Otherwise, just pick up any linear algebra textbook?